# Overcoming lack of app.config in SSIS Script Task to resolve memory exception issues

Tags: c#, ssis, out-of-memory, bids

I've got an SSIS package that loads in a large amount of data using a Script Task and I've run into memory exception issues like the following:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

These are occurring due to a `List<T>` that grows past the default limits of the framework. According to the MSDN site, I need to set the following in my app.config file:

```
<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
```

However, I can't do this because SSIS doesn't seem to read from any app.config or web.config files. This appears to be a limitation of the Script Task.

I've looked to the post [here](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Where-is-my-appconfig-for-SSIS.aspx) and looked through the different config files in the installation directory and added the XML snippet above but to no avail. Can it be done this way at all or do I have to resort to some other way around this?

Note that I'm running the process as 64bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to load all the objects in to memory at once, can you work with them as a stream or queue instead of a complete block?

Comment: The end goal is to load the data into MongoDB. I'm actually using a ConcurrentBag<T> as the calls are being made in a multi-threaded setting and the reason why I don't want to use a stream/queue is because in case of any script errors nothing should insert. Instead of setting up a delete plan in case of package/script task failures, I build the list to full capacity before I insert.

Comment: You can create a class project (with the app config) and reference the dll from the script task.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Interesting suggestion... although a quick preliminary search seems to suggest that the executing application won't benefit from those settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Where-is-my-appconfig-for-SSIS.aspx) and my experience - you need to modify either `DTExec.exe.config` for Server package exec or `DtsDebugHost.exe.config` for debugging in BIDS or VS, or change both files.
These files are located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<Version #>\DTS\Binn\`